# jquery.download fails to make API call which is [Authorize] restricted

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-plugins, asp.net-web-api2

I am trying to download a file using jquery.download plugin, for this I make an API call, but the issue is my API is under `[Authorize]` restriction, hence API call is not being made. I think it is missing Authentication header.
My function is

```
 function ExportStS(getAll, type, print) {          
            var path = api_url + 'api/SharedDocument/GetStateSummaryExport';
            $.fileDownload(path, {
                httpMethod: "POST"               
            });
            return false;
        }
```

When I see the console I see this message

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 401
>   (Unauthorized)