# Send Authorization Header while submitting a run time created HTML form

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, jquery-plugins

I am Submitting a form and calling an web api, and web API is under `[Authorize]` attribute. So the web API returns

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 401
>   (Unauthorized)

Because Authorizzation header info is missing, my JS code looks like this

```
formDoc.write("<html><head></head><body><form method='" + settings.httpMethod + "' action='" + fileUrl + "'>" + formInnerHtml + "</form>" + settings.popupWindowTitle + "</body></html>");
$form = $(formDoc).find('form');            
$form.submit();
```

How do I include auth header inside submitting form.

Comment: Can you use ajax post?

Comment: No, I am using jquery.filedownload.js plugin, which creates an iframe, an HTML form and submits it to call the Web Api, then only file is downloaded, if I use ajax post then everything will be okay but file will not be downloaded.

Comment: So, is that web api method on your server side?

Comment: Yest, it is, if you need more details, please visit this link
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41930661/jquery-download-fails-to-make-api-call-which-is-authorize-restricted

Comment: Ok, why you didn't create some session storage where you can keep authorization data? Actually, there isn't good practice to send authorization data via for get requests.

Comment: Did you manage to find any solution to attach authorization header while submitting form?